# fopen(): failed to open stream: permission denied in

Tags: php

Buenos días.
Estoy haciendo una función en php para partir una serie de archivos css, localizados en un directorio "x", en otros archivos mas pequeños y al ordenar ejecutar la función me arroja el error "fopen(): failed to open stream: Permission denied in...".

Esta misma función la he utilizado con anterioridad procesando un archivo cada vez con la función y realiza su trabajo perfectamente.

El problema viene cuando, mediante un foreach envío uno por uno los archivos del directorio "x" a la función.

Me he asegurado que las carpetas tienen permisos 0777 cambiando estos permisos a mano (utilizo appserv en local) y además desde el script se dan permisos con chmod a las carpetas implicadas.

Adjunto el código de la función por si alguien puede orientarme donde está el error...

```
function partir (){

$to_read = _PS_truncate_ . '/archivosUp' ;  //Establecemos el directorio de lectura de archivos. Las partes se crearan en el directorio to_write.
$to_write = _PS_truncate_ . '/archivosUp/chunk' ;   //Establecemos el directorio de escritura de archivos.

// Opciones No editables.

$done = false;
$part = 0;
if (($handle = fopen($to_read,'r')) !== FALSE) {
$header = fgets($handle);

while ($done == false) {
$locA = ftell($handle); // Obtiene la ubicación actual. COMIENZO
fseek($handle, $size, SEEK_CUR); // Saltar la longitud de $ size desde la posición actual
$tmp = fgets($handle); // Leer hasta el final de la línea. Queremos líneas completas
$locB = ftell($handle); // Obtiene la ubicación actual. FIN
$span = ($locB-$locA);
fseek($handle, $locA, SEEK_SET); // Saltar al inicio de este pedazo
$chunk = fread($handle,$span); // Lee, en modo binario seguro (fread), el trozo entre START y END
file_put_contents($to_write . '_' . $part.'.csv',$header.$chunk); //Escribe una cadena a un fichero (file_put_contents) formado como primer parametro por el fichero donde se escribe la información: archivo original ($to_read), guion bajo (_), la parte del csv en cuestión ($part), formato csv (.csv); como segundo parametro la información a escribir (data) encadenando $header y $chunk (lectura segura del archivo binario).
$part++;

if (strlen($chunk) < $size) $done = true; //Si la longitud del string (strlen) es menor que el tamaño indicado (Size) $done cambia a True y temina el while...
}
fclose($handle);
}

}  //Cierra la función partir.
```

Comment: Si dices que tienes permisos sobre las carpetas, revisa los permisos que tienes sobre el archivo en sí. El mensaje es incuestionable, te falta algún permiso sea a nivel de carpetas, sea a nivel de archivo directamente.

Comment: Ese es el problema...que sobre los archivos también tengo control total...

Comment: De ahí parte mi comedura de coco... ya no se que puede ser...

Comment: Ahhh, además, estás abriendo el archivo en sólo lectura: `if (($handle = fopen($to_read,'r')) !== FALSE) {`, debes cambiar la `r` por la `w` si mal no recuerdo: **`if (($handle = fopen($to_read,'w')) !== FALSE) {`** o por cualquier otro modo que te permita escribir. [Ver el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) al respecto.

Comment: Lo abro en solo lectura porque el/los archivos to_read solo tiene que leerlos. Después con la función file_put_contents () se crean los archivos to_write.

Comment: Como comentaba en la pregunta, este script realiza su trabajo correctamente si toma los archivos uno a uno; por separado, enviandole cada archivo por POST. El problema se presenta cuando le dices (mediante un foreach) que trabaje sobre un grupo de archivos; es decir, en vez de enviarle archivos uno a uno por POST se utiliza lo siguiente:

Comment: foreach (CSVcopy as $valor){   partir();   }.   Donde CSVcopy es un array con el conjunto de archivos a partir y partir () es la función expuesta al inicio de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

### El problema

El problema se encuentra en esta línea:

```
if (($handle = fopen($to_read,'r')) !== FALSE) {
```

Aquí la letra `r` indica a `fopen` que abra el archivo en modo `r`ead (sólo lectura), por lo que, cualquier intento de escritura en el archivo será denegado.

### La solución

Cambiar el modo `r` por alguno de los permitidos para escritura según el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php):

- `'w'`    Apertura para **sólo escritura**; coloca el **puntero al principio del fichero** y trunca el fichero a longitud cero. Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.
- `'w+'`    Apertura para **lectura y escritura**; coloca el **puntero al principio del fichero** y trunca el fichero a longitud cero. Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.
- `'a'`    Apertura para **sólo escritura**; coloca el **puntero al final del fichero**. Si el fichero no existe, se intenta crear. En este modo, [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fseek.php) solamente afecta a la posición de lectura; las lecturas siempre son pospuestas.
- `'a+'`    Apertura para **lectura y escritura**; coloca el **puntero al final del fichero**. Si el fichero no existe, se intenta crear. En este modo, [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fseek.php) no tiene efecto, las escrituras siempre son pospuestas.
- Etc...

Answer (score 1):

Para mi fue útil aplicar esta sentencia en **linux** 
`setenforce 0`

Y con eso dejas al `SElinux` en modo permisivo también aplique todos los permisos `chmod 777` al directorio donde cae el archivo.