# Error al mandar cadena mediante ajax a php que la escribe en un archivo de texto

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Aquí esta el código js:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ladderboard.php",
            data: {
                "json": JsonString
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                alert(JsonString);
            }

        });
```

Y el codigo php:

```
<?php 
  $json = $_POST["json"];
  $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");
  fwrite($file, $json  . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

El error que que me da en consola es que no reconoce la cadena que le estoy enviando mediante método POST.

Se agradecería toda la ayuda posible.

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras `JsonString`?

Comment: var nuevapuntuacion = Object();
            nuevapuntuacion.nombre = $("#nombre").val();
            nuevapuntuacion.puntos = $("#puntos").val();
            jsonobjeto.push(nuevapuntuacion);
            var JsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonobjeto);

Comment: la cadena me la escribe el problema es que cuando recargo la pagina se borra todo lo que hay en el archivo

Comment: Fíjate que el ajax se llama siempre que entras en la página, por lo que si no le envías nada, el fichero de texto se queda vacío, para evitarlo, puedes poner un if(isset($_POST["json"])) { y aquí tu código php, de esta forma, si entras en la web pero no está definido el post, es que no se envía nada y no hay que guardar nada.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que la forma en que intentas crear tu JSON es poco práctica, cuando no, incorrecta.

Aquí muestro varias posibles formas de hacerlo. Para más facilidad convendría poner todos los datos que quieras en un `form`.

En la primera opción te creará un JSON propiamente dicho (yo usaría esa forma preferiblemente), ya que la segunda forma te crea un Array JSON. También es válida, pero el objeto JSON se encontrará en el ìndice `0` del array.

```js
var $frm = $("#myform");

/*1ª forma: Objeto JSON propiamente dicho*/
var json = formToJSON($frm);
console.log(json);

function formToJSON($form) {
  var arrSerialize = $form.serializeArray();
  var arrNew = {};

  $.map(arrSerialize, function(n, i) {
    arrNew[n['name']] = n['value'];
  });

  return arrNew;
}

/*2ª forma: Array JSON*/
var data = JSON.stringify($frm.serializeArray());

console.log(data);

/*3ª forma: Objeto JSON manual*/
var jsonManual =
  '{"nombre":"' + $("#nombre").val() + '",' +
  '"puntos":"' + $("#puntos").val() + '"}';
console.log(jsonManual);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input id="nombre" name="nombre" value="nombre test" />
  <input id="puntos" name="puntos" value="10" />
</form>
```

En cuanto al PHP, ten en cuenta que el uso de `fopen` con `w` coloca el puntero al inicio del fichero, volviendo a escribir en él. Si quieres que se siga agregando contenido, puedes usar `a`. Para más detalles puedes ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114351/29967) y en el Manual de PHP aparece una lista más amplia de todas las posibilidades que ofrece `fopen`.